# Unable to install "merged-pooler" module nodeJs

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, mining

So I've leased a VPS from Amazon running Ubuntu Server & I'm trying to setup a Litecoin mining pool so I can point my miners to it. (This is meant to be a private pool)
So far I've installed Litecoin packages, updated, and got Litecoind up and running, all blocks downloaded and up to date. I've installed UNOMP and setup the configuration files as directed in the guide I'm using. (Found Here: https://blockgen.net/setup-your-own-mining-pool)

I'm on the very last step which is to run the init.js file and launch the pool.
Unfortunately instead of working, it throws out the following error message. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated--I've been working at this all week long and have exhausted every possible resource on Google that I can find and nothing seems to work. I'm ripping my hair out as we speak ;)

Here is the error that is being thrown out:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-26-4-125:/home/nick/unomp$ sudo node init.js


module.js:328
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'merged-pooler'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/nick/unomp/libs/poolWorker.js:1:77)
at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
```

**********UPDATE*********
Latest version of NodeJs installed
Latest version of npm install
-This has fixed the "node-gyp" error I was receiving.
The only thing left to do is get 'sudo npm install merged-pooler' to work. It is now kicking out a much smaller different error that I've tried to research but can't find anything on, posted below:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-26-4-125:/home/nick/unomp$ sudo npm install merged-pooler
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone --depth=1 -q -b master 
git://github.com/UNOMP/node-merged-pool.git 
/home/ubuntu/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-a85b3ede
npm ERR! /home/ubuntu/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-a85b3ede/.git: Permission 
denied
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2017-07-31T23_29_34_792Z-debug.log
ubuntu@ip-172-26-4-125:/home/nick/unomp$
```

Comment: have you run npm install?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried running that command and it's kicking out another error:

Comment: is the error about not being able to find a package.json file?

Comment: gyp ERR! build error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/share/node-
    gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
    gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
    (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
    gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1026-aws
    gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
    gyp ERR! cwd /home/nick/unomp/node_modules/unomp-multi-hashing

Comment: did you try to run it as sudo?

Comment: Its actually much longer then that. It'd be a massive amount of text to dump on here

Comment: Yes, as a habit I've been running everything as sudo so I don't get permission errors

Comment: there are several suggestions here to try https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/809, otherwise edit the question and post the full stacktrace

Comment: With some help I found out i'm not running a current version of NodeJS. Ubuntu LTS told me I had the current version when in fact i'm running V4.x and the new LTS version of Node is 6.x, with 8.x being current release.

Comment: I'm trying to update Node now, but for some reason the commands aren't working that theyve descibed (https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/)

Comment: curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an npm package [merged-pooler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merged-pooler), which you can install with

```
npm install merged-pooler
```

Comment: When I tried that I get this massive error that begins with:

Comment: 'Release/obj.target/multihashing/multihashing.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/multihashing/multihashing.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/nick/unomp/node_modules/unomp-multi-hashing/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/share/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem. I managed to solve it by running the following commands. Note: Execute as root:

```
source ~/.profile
nvm install 0.10.25
nvm use 0.10.25
apt install redis
npm update
npm install bignum
npm install stratum-pool
npm install merged-pooler
```

And then, finally try running your pool node:

```
node init.js
```

Good luck!