# Access denied error when trying to issue npm update on a Nodejs project

Tags: node.js, npm

so this is part of an earlier problem I had. Most all has been fixed. Origional problem can be viewed ([Unable to install "merged-pooler" module nodeJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45425523/unable-to-install-merged-pooler-module-nodejs))

So from what I understand I need to update npm so I can download the 'merged-pooler' module, but when I try to update npm I get this weird permission or access denied error;

```
nick@ip-172-26-4-125:~/unomp$ sudo npm update
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone --depth=1 -q -b master 
git://github.com/n0mad01/node.bittrex.api.git 
/home/nick/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-dd7ed0cd
npm ERR! /home/nick/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-dd7ed0cd/.git: Permission 
denied
npm ERR!
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/nick/.npm/_logs/2017-08-01T04_45_33_632Z-debug.log
nick@ip-172-26-4-125:~/unomp$
```